# Add and remove class in table rows JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a hierarchal table where I am adding first class name dynamically. I want to add another class (for example – `active`) when user click a row and remove when click again. If not click again in the same row then it will be remain same (`active`) and if click into another row, it will add active class there. I do not want to use `toggleClass` because I already used this in another function. The code I tried, is not working properly.

My table structure is –

```
<table id="tbl_data">
<tr class="t1" ><td><div><a href="#">test1</a></div></td></tr>
<tr class="t2" ><td><div><a href="#">test2</a></div></td></tr>
<tr class="t3" ><td><div><a href="#">test3</a></div></td></tr>
</table>



var lvl = '@h_lbl'; (eg: cls1)                                  

$('table#tbl_data tbody tr.' + lvl).on('click', function (event) {

if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
    $(this).removeClass('active');
else            
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
var table = $('#tble_data');    

table.on('click', 'tr', function () {

    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks John, it works but I remove this line ($('tr.active').removeClass('active');). because I want to keep the class name if user not click again. Many thanks for your assistance

Comment: Yes of course. I didn't understand that in your question sorry. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use toggleClass instead of an if/else. In the end it is the same thing under the covers, but it is simpler to maintain.

```js
//Event delegation on the tbody allows for one event to be attached
$("#tbl_data tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
    //toggle class does the check to add/remove the class
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    //If only one row can be selected
    //$(this).siblings(".selected").removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
table tr, td { border: 1px solid black; padding: .5em; }
.selected {
    background-color: yellow;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl_data">
<tr class="t1" ><td><div><a href="#">test1</a></div></td></tr>
<tr class="t2" ><td><div><a href="#">test2</a></div></td></tr>
<tr class="t3" ><td><div><a href="#">test3</a></div></td></tr>
</table>
```